# Set header for default posts page?

Tags: homepage, custom-header

In *Settings/Reading* I set *Testimonials* as post page.

How can I change the header of that page?

Comment: I'm using condoma theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a template. You just have to copy the file `header.php` and call the new file with the slug of the page `testimonials`. It would require 2 new files :

`header-testimonials.php` and `front-page.php`.

then you can call your custom header with `get_header('testimonials');`

See the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). Just be sure Testimonials is your front page.

**EDIT:** Regarding front page (1rst page of the site) WP looks into your theme and the first file to be called is `front-page.php`. Most of the time WP blogs set front page as posts page (reading settings).

Here your can set another file as custom header and call it in `front-page.php` it will be called on front page automatically.

You could also insert some conditional tags in the main `header.php` but it's better to use `front-page.php` when cutomizing front page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have already the replace the home page. What I happen is to use the default post page and change its header. Can you elaborate it more because I'm a newbie in wordpress. Thank you

Comment: sure I'm editing

Comment: Wow your great dude! Thanks, you save my day. God bless you. Thanks!